# Error auto-report for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a Rails gem that automatically e-mails me whenever theres a error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're operating a low-volume site and just want to get an email whenever an exception bubbles to the top, you might be looking for the [exception notification gem](https://github.com/rails/exception_notification).

Answer (score 3):

There's a number of these services. My favourites are [Exceptional](http://getexceptional.com) and [Hoptoad](http://hoptoadapp.com).